# Get Discount Amount on success.phtml

Tags: magento-1.9

I have the below code on success.phtml to get some order info.  I also need to be able to get the discount amount (if any) on the order.  This would be the discount amount from any discount codes used.

```
<?php
/*Use this to get sale attributes - to get additional view the code in app>code>core>mage>googleanalytics>block>ga.php*/
$lastOrderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId();
$order = Mage::getSingleton('sales/order');
$order->load($lastOrderId);
$_grandTotal = $order->getBaseGrandTotal(); #order total
$orderNumber = $this->__($this->getOrderId()); #order number
$voucher = $order->getCouponCode(); #voucher code used
$_totalData =$order->getData(); 
    $_sub = $_totalData['subtotal'];
    $_sub = round($_sub,2); 
    $currency = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
    $currency_symbol = Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode())->getSymbol();
?>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can load `order` object then you should be able to get discount by this simple code:

```
$order->getDiscountAmount();
```

Moreover, if you want to see all applied discount codes then:

```
$items = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')->getCollection()
    ->addFilter('order_id',array('eq'=>$lastOrderId));

foreach($items as $item){
    if($item->getAppliedRuleIds() == '') {
        continue;
    }
    foreach(explode(",",$item->getAppliedRuleIds()) as $ruleId){       
         //Load the rule object
        $rule = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->load($ruleId); //Shopping Cart Rules //$rule = Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule')->load($ruleId); catalog rules
        // Throw out some information like the rule name what product it was applied to
        echo "<p> Applied Rule Name: ".$rule->getName()." & Code : ".$rule->getCouponCode()."</p>";
        echo "\t";
    }
}
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$orderDetails = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($this->getOrderId());

echo "Your Coupon code is==".$orderDetails->getCouponCode();//display coupon code

$discountTotal = 0; 
$items =$orderDetails->getAllItems();
foreach($items as $item)
{
        $discountTotal += $item->getDiscountAmount();
} 
echo "Discount Amount is".$discountTotal;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to avail discount amount on success:

```
<?php
    $order_id = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId();
    $order_details = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($order_id);
    echo $order_details->getDiscountAmount();
?>
```